# DKIM set up in SES but shown not set up in G suite Toolbox Check MX

Tags: amazon-ses, google-workspace, dkim

In SES under domains I see

[image]

But in Gsuite https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/ I ran a test for my domain and the result is

[image]

Currently I am using SES and sending email from one of the gsuite email address. Do I need to also set up DKIM in Gsuite as well?

Answer (score 0):

Have you entered Amazon SES DKIM selector in Googele Toolbox ?

If you did not, it will assume that selector is google.

SES send emails signed by its own DKIM, but anyway, it make sense to setup DKIM foror G Sute to have your G Suite sent emails also properly authenticated.